# Jquery hide doesn't work with duration

Tags: jquery, hide

I am using jquery's hide functionality on an svg element, and it works fine unless I try to specify a duration:

```
// Hide the object: works fine
$('#id').hide()

// Doesn't work with time specified in any of these attempts including fadeout
$('#id').hide('slow')
$('#id').hide(400)
$('#id').hide(400, function() {console.log('done')})
$('#id').fadeOut()
$('#id').fadeOut(400)
```

EDIT: This is what the console shows:

```
// Works
$('#HTI2010').hide()
[
<circle cx=​"50" cy=​"450" id=​"HTI2010" r=​"10" class=​"c2010" title style=​"display:​ none;​ ">​</circle>​
]

// Doesn't work: display is set to in-line instead of none:  is there an argument I can alter to change this?

$('#HTI2010').hide(400)
[
<circle cx=​"50" cy=​"450" id=​"HTI2010" r=​"10" class=​"c2010" title style=​"display:​ inline;​ ">​</circle>​
]
```

The object remains on the screen for these.  Am I missing something?  Thanks,

Comment: There must be some specific error on your browser.

Comment: Can you post the code on jsfiddle?

Comment: Works here http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/DbRMD/ (although it's pretty ugly).

Comment: Thanks for showing on the jsfiddle -- perhaps my edit will help explain issue

Comment: Works for me as well, all options. Thanks @j08691 for the fiddle so I could get the SVG element to work. http://jsfiddle.net/Palpatim/qjSr6/  What browser are you using, mike?

Comment: I'm using Chrome -- just re-downloaded, so no plug-ins or viruses getting in the way

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
var duration = 400;

$('#id').hide(duration);
```